# Como reducir tamaño de texto y padding de un elemento mat-tap de angular material

Tags: html, css, angular-material

estoy tratando de reducir el padding y cambiar el tamaño de letra de un elemento mat-tap de angular material, pero no logro conseguirlo.

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Igual te sirve esto: [angular material customize tab](https://localcoder.org/angular-material-customize-tab)

Comment: @adrigo me sirvio de muchisimo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Para la próxima, te recomiendo buscar en Google antes de preguntar, ya que si preguntas aquí puede que nunca te respondan o que tu pregunta sea mal recibida, yo he realizado una sola búsqueda en Google y abierto los dos primeros links, te he mandado uno de ellos pero ambos servían. A lo que me refiero es que posiblemente tardes menos buscando en Google que esperando una respuesta. Un saludo :)

Comment: Por otro lado, marca la pregunta como cerrada. Si necesitas tener una respuesta para hacerlo, dime y te pongo para que al menos puedas cerrarla.

Comment: Si gracias por el consejo, no encuentro la manera de cerrar mi pregunta ;(

Comment: Te pongo una respuesta entonces, aunque sea una tontería para que puedas finalizarla y la gente vea que está completada y les ayude si tienen tu mismo problema. Márcala como respuesta aceptada y ya estaría. Si le das un upvote tambien ayuda. :)

Answer (score 3):

He encontrado post con diferentes formas de solucionarlo que igual te sirve:

[angular material customize tab](https://localcoder.org/angular-material-customize-tab)